# Server programs see my IP instead of actual client IP as the source of incoming connections

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding

Any server program (Apache, netcat with -l, Minecraft server) can't see the IP of the connecting client.
Instead they see the connection as coming from my own public IP (but from some weird port).
I have no idea what is causing this but because it happens on all machines in the network, I will quickly go over my router setup too.

I have two routers, one provided by the ISP and a pretty standard WIFI router.
The one from the ISP is set to "Bridge Mode" which, according to the ISP, disables NAT, Firewall and Routing. It should only function as a modem.
This seems to work, the WIFI router reports my actual public IP as the WAN IP.

The ports are port-forwarded and the services work normally.

On a side note, I read that some proxies would fill in the HTTP "X-Forwarded-For" field. This is not the case here.

Comment: Is the connecting client _in the same LAN_ as the server?

Comment: @user1686 No, I have tried from my phone using mobile data and had a friend connect to the website. Minecraft players were also not in the LAN.

Comment: What WAN IP does your router get? I mean from it's web page or settings app, NOT what your PC would see? My guess is that your ISP's modem/router is not really in bridge mode, but is performing a 1:1 NAT (if your router reports it's WAN IP as a private IP that is the case, if it reports a true public IP then we need to look at something else). Either that, or your router just does not handle port forwarding properly and is reporting the incorrect IP, but you did not state your specific router.

Comment: @acejavelin Thank you for the reply. The router does indeed show its WAN IP to be my public IP in the  web interface. It's a TL-WR841N. Is there some way to check if it's that router? Are there any router options I should try changing? I tried the "DMZ" feature which is just an exposed host (no port forwarding required) but the problem remained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would like to apologize for my imprecise question, it's my first time here.

I was referring to packets coming from the internet.

I have now found out that it's a quirk of one of the routers (unfortunately I can't test which because i don't have any other routers to test with).

It is either the port forwarding of the **TP-LINK TL-WR841N** wifi router or something about the **cbn CH7466CE** in "Bridge Mode" as a modem.

My workaround is simply to turn off "Bridge Mode" and use that router as the main router of the household. The wifi router is still connected for wifi but all the computers (including crucially the server that I was having the issue with) are now connected to the router I was using a modem.

Answer (score 0):

Your internal IP addresses have no meaning on the internet.
Your one and only IP address on the internet is the one assigned to you by the ISP.

Any server on the internet cannot distinguish between any and all of your computers and
will see them as coming from the same address.

The magic that makes it work is called
[Network address translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation),
which is done by the router that houses the
[DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)
server.

Study well the above links.

Comment: The problem is that my server can't see the source of the incoming packets when they come from a different household.

Comment: That depends on what you are doing. Much more detail is required in order to answer where is the problem.

Comment: I know but I have no idea what's causing this so I don't know what I need to tell you. My current suspicion is that my router isn't port forwarding correctly but I don't know how to test this.

Comment: More probably this is because of how you are asking about the IP. If this is inside a program, the question is more suitable for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). If this is the way you are using a server, you can start a new post here with the required details.

Comment: This happens on all devices in the network that I have tried (Linux, Windows, Mac OS)  and with all programs that I have tried (`netcat -l`, Apache Webserver, `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, Minecraft Server).

Comment: Can you add more information in your post about your setup? Are you connecting from the LAN or via the internet?

Comment: I'm having friends connect via the internet

Comment: Then the problem is with the way the server is picking the IP address, just doing it wrong, because that information is available.